# Max number of concurrent connections to DB2, biggest table size?

Tags: sql, database, db2, database-connection

What is the maximum of simultaneous connections which DB2 can handle? The connection can be from one App or can be from different apps from same or different applications.

Also, how much data can DB2 hold in its tables? In one table and in all the Tables? What is the approximate max number of records and the size of data?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer typical depends on your system resources. The DB2 documentation ("Knowledge Center") has a section on "[SQL and XML Limits](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001029.html)". There you will find the specific system limits, including maximum concurrency and table sizes.

Without any additional software, the maximum concurrency (parallel connections) is 64000.

The maximum table size requires some math. It depends on tablespaces, table organization, page size, number of columns and more. How many petabytes of storages does your system has available...?

Comment: ok..storage means of whole system hard disk or RAM?
and one more thing I have an database instance in it there is one database and two tablespace  for  two different java web applications.
Now we have to implement for new java web application so what is the best way to do this.
Should we create a new instance,new database ,a new table space..pls suggest.

I have less idea about storage so please explain me from basics.

Thanks,